# Changing the training behavior of batch normalization layer in a pre-built model

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I have been doing a bit of reading on the behavior of batch normalization layers in transfer learning, and I found [this paper](https://openreview.net/pdf?id=TjwDWRdfZpg) to be quite helpful. It seems that quite a bit of progress can be made during fine tuning during transfer learning by only training the learned parameters of the batch normalization layers of the transfer model. To do this, the trainable parameter of batch normalization layers in tensorflow needs to be set to True.

However, this will also set the training parameter to True if my understanding is correct, as I am using tensorflow v. 2.1. While "trainable" controls if weights are updated, "training" controls the behavior of layers that behave differently in training and instance modes, like dropout or batch normalizaiton layers. In order to prevent the saved average and standard deviation from being updated (which will destroy the model's performance), the batch normalization layer needs to remain in instance mode, which would correpond to a "Training" state of False.

The problem that the training state of the layers in the pre-built transfer model that I am using can not be easily set. While I can change the trianability by pulling a layer out and setting layer.trainable = True for example, training is not an attirbute but a parameter used by the call function, so it cannot be easily set like this. The examples I am able to find adjust the training state when building the model sequentially. I cannot do this as my model is pre-built.

Right now, I have to keep the batch normalization layers from training at all. I can get decent results this way, but I would like to be able to train beta and gamma, as I have read that this alone can be quite powerful. Please let me know if this is possible in tensorflow and if so how I would go about making the adjustment. Thanks!